# SQL Server : find Instance of values that deviate

Tags: sql-server, currency, standard-deviation

Scenario: I have bills on various accounts, stored in a SQL Server database, over a series of months.

i.e.

```
AccountNum     BillNum      BillMonth   BillTotal       
---------------------------------------------------
123456         123456-1      201601     $100000.00    
123456         123456-2      201602     $100000.00    
123456         123456-3      201603     $100000.00    
123456         123456-4      201604     $130000.00    
456789         456789-1      201601     $250000.00    
456789         456789-2      201602     $250000.00    
456789         456789-3      201603     $250000.00    
456789         456789-4      201604     $200000.00
```

I am trying to write a query that will show outliers/deviations that differ by > xx% for a given time period. So in the above dataset, row 4 and 8 differ substantially from what I would consider the "normal" amount of $100,000 p/month, potentially indicating an issue.

I need a way to average the bills by account (as each account has a different bill/charges etc) and find where the deviation is more than say 10% for a given month.

I have tried using STDEV but can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following query:

```
SELECT AccountNum, BillNum, BillMonth, BillTotal,
       CASE 
          WHEN ABS(BillTotal - AVG(BillTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNum)) > 
               STDEV(BillTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNum)
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS deviates
FROM mytable
```

The above query returns a `1` for those records having a `BillTotal` amount that deviates more than the standard deviation from the average value of the field for the specific `AccountNum`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will work. I still have another issue with this, where there are multiple bills for the account within the month. I think I will just include accounts that only have 1 bill, as it would probably be too erroneous otherwise.